# How can I set status messages in IRC?

Tags: irc

How can I set status messages in IRC? A simple guide for learning IRC would also be helpful.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The standard command is /away [your away message]. Then /away again to let people know you're back. I think this is a good start for learning IRC: http://www.mirc.com/ircintro.html

Answer (score 21):

You can do something like `/away` to set yourself as being away. For instance:

```
/away Not here right now
```

This will make it appear to others that you are away, and if they PM you, they will get a message somewhat like this:

```
Menopia is away. Reason: Not here right now
```

You can also use the `/me` command to denote doing something. For instance:

```
/me does something
```

Will appear to others in the channel/PM as something like:

```
* Menopia does something
```

Comment: is there a comment that would just set my status (in my /whois and direct messages) and not spam all channels that I am in? Maybe its diturbing if I change this a lot